# Settings.bundle not respecting app group on iOS simulator or device

Tags: nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle, ios-app-group

I had been using `standardUserDefaults` until recently but decided to use shared app groups because I created a watch extension.  I have set up an app group and also added the `ApplicationGroupContainerIdentifier` to the settings bundle.

I have spent hours on this and, even after reading many articles, I just can’t get this to work.  I am seeing that when I **alloc** my app group and print its contents, it has default values from `standardUserDefaults`.
All I am doing is `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName: SUITE_NAME]]` and then print its contents on the very next line.
I am puzzled by how it has values from my settings bundle.  Moreover, when you edit the properties using the settings app, the settings in `standardUserDefaults` are changing but my app group values stay the same.

I see the same behaviour on the simulator and real device.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be user error.  There was a typo in the app group name as a result of the auto-correct feature.  I did not realize it until I created a new app group.